# What is causing this issue loading the MASS package in R?

Tags: r

I am having trouble loading a package in R. I began by removing the package:

```
> remove.packages("MASS")
Removing package from ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
```

I then install it:

```
> install.packages("MASS")

  There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
     binary source needs_compilation
MASS 7.3-48 7.3-49              TRUE

Do you want to install from sources the package which needs compilation?
```

I answer yes to this question:

```
y/n: y
installing the source package ‘MASS’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/MASS_7.3-49.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 487772 bytes (476 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 476 KB

* installing *source* package ‘MASS’ ...
** package ‘MASS’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
clang -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/X11/include    -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c MASS.c -o MASS.o
clang -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/X11/include    -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c lqs.c -o lqs.o
clang -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -L/usr/local/lib -o MASS.so MASS.o lqs.o -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation
installing to /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/MASS/libs
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (MASS)

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/2p/3h5yk1gx4fs1gd8gtdbhdd900000gn/T/RtmpHT4qCQ/downloaded_packages’
```

To be honest, I don't understand the messages I get here, but they seem to suggest that the installation was successful. So I then try to load the package, and get a slew of errors:

```
> library(MASS)
Error in get(method, envir = home) : 
  lazy-load database '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/MASS/R/MASS.rdb' is corrupt
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In .registerS3method(fin[i, 1], fin[i, 2], fin[i, 3], fin[i, 4],  :
  restarting interrupted promise evaluation
2: In get(method, envir = home) :
  restarting interrupted promise evaluation
3: In get(method, envir = home) : internal error -3 in R_decompress1
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘MASS’
```

I've tried updating R Studio to the latest version but that didn't help. If anyone could begin to point me in the right direction I'd be very grateful.

Comment: What is your operating system? `MASS` is sometimes managed at the operating system level (see https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/README.html)

Comment: Why are you trying to update MASS? It's part of the base R distribution, so you generally update it by updating R itself. The version on CRAN will be appropriate for the latest R version, which from the above is not the version you've got.

Comment: @HongOoi I had been trying to load a package called mixOmics. It hung while trying to load MASS, so I thought that reinstalling it might fix the issue. I didn't know that it was part of R itself.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem arises because of selecting 'yes' to the question about compiling sources. I have the latest version of R and RStudio on Windows 10, and this is what I see when I try to install MASS:

> install.packages("MASS")
>   Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Ruth/Documents/R/win-library/3.4’
>   (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
>   trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/MASS_7.3-49.zip'
>   Content type 'application/zip' length 1169454 bytes (1.1 MB)
>   downloaded 1.1 MB

Since I am not being prompted to answer that question, I cannot say for sure, but that message often means that the package has updated recently on CRAN but the binary isn’t yet available for your OS (it can take a day or two). According to [this page](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MASS/index.html), the MASS package was updated as recently as 2018-02-23, so that might be why. There are probably other scenarios when the binary isn’t available for your platform.

If you say no to that question, you won’t get the most recent version. But this might be just fine, unless you were specifically installing because of an update. I would try that.

If you say yes, the package will be built from source locally. If it has compiled code and you’ve never set up build tools for R, then this won’t actually succeed. I think that is why you are having the problem. Hopefully answering 'no' will solve your problem.

If not, I would update R to the latest version  (it should be Kite-Eating Tree). I know you have updated to the latest RStudio, but R is a separate software and is currently on version 3.4.3. From your code, it seems you are running a 3.3 version. Get the latest version here: https://cran.r-project.org/

Hope this helps, Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks very much! That really cleared things up! I will try what you suggest.

Comment: You're welcome, I hope it works. I'm quite new to R and stack overflow, so I appreciate the feedback. Feel free to leave a vote on the answer if you'd like to.